# Plot the Geometry of one row of a GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I would like to plot the geometry contained in a single row of a geopandas dataframe, but I am having problems. Here an example

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p1 = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)])
p2 = Polygon([(2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1), (2, 1)])
p3 = Polygon([(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)])
index = np.random.random(3)
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
df['index'] = index
df['geometry'] = [p1,p2,p3]
df = df.set_geometry('geometry')
```

Now if I plot using the command `df.plot()` I get

[image]

but if I try to plot only one row, `df.loc[:,0].plot()`

I get the following error

`TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot`,

while if if i try

`df.loc[:,'geometry'].plot()`

I get `AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'plot'`

What is the correct way of doing this ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
df.loc[[0],'geometry'].plot()
#      ^ ^
```

Explanation: `shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon` *doesn't* have `.plot()` method:

```
In [19]: type(df.loc[0,'geometry'])
Out[19]: shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon
```

`geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries` *does* have `.plot()` method:

```
In [20]: type(df.loc[[0],'geometry'])
Out[20]: geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries
```